# Insert elements into an XML document derived from existing content

Tags: powershell, vbscript, jscript

I have an XML file like this:

```xml
<game id="748" source="ScreenScraper">
  <path>./Tecmo Super Bowl (U) (Sep 1993) [!].zip</path>
  <name>Tecmo Super Bowl</name>
  <desc>Tecmo returns to the gridiron with this new version of Tecmo Super Bowl for 16-bit console systems. Play with real National Football League players and teams in this 2D, side-scrolling arcade game.</desc>
  <image>~/.emulationstation/downloaded_images/megadrive/Tecmo Super Bowl (U) (Sep 1993) [!]-image.png</image>
  <rating>0.85</rating>
  <releasedate>19930000T000000</releasedate>
  <developer>Tecmo</developer>
  <publisher>Tecmo</publisher>
  <genre>Sports</genre>
  <players>1-2</players>
  <crc32>0F02FBFC</crc32>
  <md5>FEC698E5387617B11C81431894B12EDC</md5>
  <sha1>77AF672321947C3F8F80F7AE7ADFF8CDE0E2986A</sha1>
</game>
<game id="1014" source="ScreenScraper">
  <path>./Action 52 (Unl) [!].zip</path>
  <name>Action 52</name>
  <desc>Action 52 features 52 different games in a single cartridge! The games are selected from one of three menus and are mostly side scrolling, platform or shooter action games.</desc>
  <image>~/.emulationstation/downloaded_images/megadrive/Action 52 (Unl) [!]-image.png</image>
  <rating>0.1</rating>
  <releasedate>19930000T000000</releasedate>
  <developer>Active Enterprises Ltd.</developer>
  <publisher>Active Enterprises</publisher>
  <genre>Compilation</genre>
  <players>1-2</players>
  <crc32>7B544625</crc32>
  <md5>D32F3F2825DB4AE40D51317BBFF7330E</md5>
  <sha1>3D9C1984B5F1B385EBDFF34218FEA6BCE83C43B6</sha1>
</game>
<game id="103612" source="ScreenScraper">
  <path>./Bug's Life, A (Unl) [!].zip</path>
  <name>A Bug's Life</name>
  <developer>X BOY</developer>
  <publisher>X BOY</publisher>
  <genre>Action</genre>
  <crc32>6EBECD9A</crc32>
  <md5>27122254E417C44A35310E6D39B61D4A</md5>
  <sha1>441A0E019EB32106D1AFD2ED97F117B007299F5B</sha1>
</game>
```

I need a batch file to read the value of name for each game and add two new lines like this for each game:

```xml
<video>~/.emulationstation/roms/megadrive/Videos/%gamename%.mp4</video>
<marquee>~/.emulationstation/roms/megadrive/Marquees/%gamename%.png</marquee>
```

Where `%gamename%` must be the name of the game between `<name>` and `</name>`.

I have made this batch script, but it doesn't work:

```batch
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
set "gamename="
for /f "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%a in ( 'find /i "<name>" ^< "gamelist.xml"' ) do set "gamename=%%a"
(for /F "delims=" %%a in (gamelist.xml) do (
  set "newLine=!line:"~/.emulationstation/roms/megadrive/Videos/%gamename%.mp4"
  echo !newLine!
)) > newFile.xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most robust solution is to **use an XML parser**, and **PowerShell** allows easy access to one:

```
# Read the XML file into an XML DOM ([System.Xml.XmlDocument] or [xml], for short).
# Note: If your file truly has no single root XML element, 
#       use ('<xml>' + (Get-Content ...) + '</xml>')  
$doc = [xml] (Get-Content -raw gamelist.xml)

# Loop over all <game> elements.
foreach ($gameEl in $doc.DocumentElement.game) { 
  $gameName = $gameEl.name
  # Append the new elements, using string interpolation to set the inner text
  # (note the references to variable ${gameName} inside the double-quoted string).
  $gameEl.AppendChild($doc.CreateElement('video')).InnerText = "~/.emulationstation/roms/megadrive/Videos/${gameName}.mp4"
  $gameEl.AppendChild($doc.CreateElement('marquee')).InnerText = "~/.emulationstation/roms/megadrive/Marquees/${gameName}.png"
}

# Save the modified XML to a new file, using the .NET framework's default
# UTF-8 encoding without a BOM.
$writer = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "$PWD/newFile.xml"
$doc.Save($writer)
$writer.Close()
```

---

A variant requested by the OP that uses the extension-less filename of the path contained in the `<path>` element instead of the `<name>` element's value, and only adds elements `video` and `marquee` if they don't already exist:

```
$doc = [xml] (Get-Content -raw gamelist.xml)

foreach ($gameEl in $doc.DocumentElement.game) { 
  # Use -replace to extract the filename without extension from the 
  # path contained in the <path> element.
  $gameName = $gameEl.path -replace '^.*/(.*)\..*$', '$1'
  # Append elements 'video' and 'marquee', but only if they don't already
  # exist.
  if ($null -eq $gameEl.video) {
    $gameEl.AppendChild($doc.CreateElement('video')).InnerText = "~/.emulationstation/roms/megadrive/Videos/${gameName}.mp4"
  }
  if ($null -eq $gameEl.marquee) {
    $gameEl.AppendChild($doc.CreateElement('marquee')).InnerText = "~/.emulationstation/roms/megadrive/Marquees/${gameName}.png"
  }
}

$writer = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "$PWD/newFile.xml"
$doc.Save($writer)
$writer.Close()
```